# MySQL using * along with column names from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I want to select all the fields from one table and also some specific fields from other tables using `LEFT JOIN`. Can I use the * to select all the columns from the one table and also name the specific fields from the `JOIN`?

Something like this:

```
SELECT * , table2.a, table2.b 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.a = table1.a
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the fields from table1 and only certain columns from table2 you would use:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.column, table2.column
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.a = table1.a
WHERE ...
```

Comment: AHA! Thanks. 
@njk The reason I want to do this is precisely because my column list will change and my query is built dynamically. So I need it to handle several tables with similar structure elegantly.

Comment: Related follow-up question: my query has a `GROUP_CONCAT` so I use a `GROUP BY` clause to prevent cartesian products. Is there any way to reconcile these two strategies? My `GROUP BY` lists each column by name, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm guessing something like this WON'T work: `GROUP BY table1.*, table2.a, table2.b ...`

Comment: @Emerson You must specify column names with GROUP BY - sorry

Answer (score 1):

Syntax wise, it is correct and works. However, it is poor practice to use `*`. I would recommend you always specify a column list. If the columns change, your application may break. It's also always better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You specify all columns from one table with `table1.*` If you use `*` you will get *all* columns from *all* tables.

MySQL is fussy about the order of wildcarded column names - they have to be first.